# BitBucket Rest API OAuth2: How to use Client Credentials Grant

Tags: oauth, bitbucket-api

I am trying to use bullet 4 ( Client Credentials Grant ) in order to obtain an access/bearer token [authentication documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication)

Example:

```
  curl -X POST -u "client_id:secret" \
  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

I have created an OAuth Consumer. I take the "Secret" that is generated from this Consumer and simply plug it in the example above for "secret", and I receive an "unauthorized client" result, when I expect to get back an access token.

Result:

```
{"error_description": "Invalid OAuth client credentials", "error": "unauthorized_client"}%
```

I have also ensured the consumer I have created as all permissions available.

Am I plugging the wrong value into the secret section? Or what else could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: This error typically means that your client_id is wrong or not encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace also client_id by the key of your consumer as you replaced de secret
"client_id:secret" => "key:secret"